# Calculate value if outside time range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem where I need to figure out if a project has values outside it's start and finish date range.

Below is a simple relationship of dimension table containing start and finish dates of the projects. And a fact table containing time registration.

[image]

The table below has a column 'Outside Date Range' Which I'd like to have a true/false value. for example if Main2 Table contains a date Monday, May 13, 2018. The column should show false.

[image]

I tried something like

`Outside Date Range = CALCULATE(SUM(Main2[Value]), FILTER(Main2, Main2[Time] < LOOKUPVALUE(Main[Start], Main[Project], ALL(Main2[Project]))))`

But not really sure how to approach the relationship between the two tables properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two approaches I would suggest are either a calculated column or a measure.

Calculated column:

```
Outside Date Range =
VAR rowsOutsideRange =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( Main2 ),
        FILTER (
            RELATEDTABLE ( Main2 ),
            Main2[Time] < Main[Start]
                || Main2[Time] > Main[Finish]
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( rowsOutsideRange > 0, TRUE (), FALSE () )
```

You were pretty close in your solution! Since you have a relationship between the two tables `RELATEDTABLE` will only return the related rows which removes the necessity of a `LOOKUPVALUE()`. Also, counting the rows is sufficient since we only want to know if any rows exist outside of the range, not how many.

You could also create a measure:

```
Outside Date Range Measure :=
VAR rowsOutsideRange =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( Main2 ),
        FILTER (
            Main2,
            Main2[Time] < MIN ( Main[Start] )
                || Main2[Time] > MAX ( Main[Finish] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( rowsOutsideRange > 0, TRUE (), FALSE () )
```

Which is pretty similar to the calculated column, the only this is we need to aggregate the start and finish dates. On its own this measure doesn't have any value, it needs to be sliced by a project to be correct. If you would really want to you could use a `SUMX()` type of construction to create an overall TRUE/FALSE statement which tells you if any of the project have rows outside their ranges but for your use case I don't see the benefit of that.

The choice between a calculated column and a measure is dependent on the legibility of the code and resource usage. A calculated measure uses more memory and a measure uses more CPU.

Looking at your case I would go for a calculated column, which seems the most simple and clear solution.

Hope that helps!

Jan

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks alot for your help. I went with the measure :)